# Active Directory Integrating Applications: Access Token Invalid

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm following this tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications) to create an App for OAUTH to Add New Users to my Azure Cloud Subscriptions.

As stated in the tutorial, I've created my App, Assigned the Permissions and performed created the secret Key.

What I'm doing is quite "standard" and still it's not working.

Let me show the steps:

```
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[CLIENTID]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&prompt=admin_consent
```

Logging in I successfully go to:

[image: Permission Request]

This after Acceptance I get to my Service where I compose my "final step" in code Authentication to retrieve Token

```
            var content = new StringContent(
            "grant_type=authorization_code" +
            "&client_id=" + Connectors.Azure.AzureHelper.ID +
            "&client_secret=" + Connectors.Azure.AzureHelper.Secret +
            "&code=" + code +
            "&resource=" + Connectors.Azure.AzureHelper.ID +
            "&redirect_uri=" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0],
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var resp = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", content);
            var text = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Connectors.Office365.AuthResp>(text);
```

In token.access_token I have a "well-formed" token.

In the token.Scopes I have also a lot of "granted permissions" like:

```
 Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Group.Read.All Group.ReadWrite.All Member.Read.Hidden User.Read User.Read.All User.ReadBasic.All
```

But If I try to perform the simplest operation like:

[image: Error on get users]

It's like I'm retrieving a Valid Token but with no capabilities!
What could be wrong?

In the Resource field of the "Code Confirmation" I put the ID of my Application. Is that correct? 
What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I find out WHAT was going wrong. Everything is about "Resource" Field in the request of the token.

Now my login URL specifies that I want a token for https://graph.api.net:

```
 var myUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=" + AzureHelper.ID + "&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + baseUrl + "/Account/OAuth&prompt=admin_consent&resource=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("https://graph.windows.net");
```

that gives me this URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[ID]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[URL]&prompt=admin_consent&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net
```

Then, at the CODE verification I request the same Resource:

```
            var content = new StringContent(
            "grant_type=authorization_code" +
            "&client_id=" + Connectors.Azure.AzureHelper.ID +
            "&client_secret=" + Connectors.Azure.AzureHelper.Secret +
            "&code=" + code +
            "&resource=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("https://graph.windows.net")+ //Connectors.Azure.AzureHelper.ID +
            "&redirect_uri=" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0],
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var resp = await client.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token", content);
            var text = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Connectors.Office365.AuthResp>(text);
```

And everything works like a Charm.

My specific problem is due to the fact that, in the first tests, I tried to put the Request parameter WITHOUT doing the URL Encoding.

The strange fact is that for the "redirect_uri" you don't need a specific encoding while you need it for the "request"

Comment: Do note that the resource URI `https://graph.windows.net` is for Azure AD Graph API, while `https://graph.microsoft.com` is for the Microsoft Graph API.